# How to correctly implement protocol - delegate pattern between UIViewController and UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am having trouble implementing a protocol-delegate pattern from a subclassed `UIView` into a `UIViewController`

Currently, this is what I have:

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,OVAddPersonDialogViewDelegate {

//MARK: IBActions

@IBAction func barBtnActionAdd(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    addPersonDialogView!.showInView(self.view)
}

//MARK: Variables

var addPersonDialogView: OVAddPersonDialogView?


//MARK: View LifeCycle

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.addPersonDialogView = OVAddPersonDialogView(frame: self.view.bounds)
    self.addPersonDialogView!.addressList = ["Address1", "Address2", "Address3"]
    addPersonDialogView!.setDelegate(self)

}

//MARK: OVAddPersonDialogViewDelegate

func onClose() {
    println("Close")
}

func onOpen(){
    println("Open")
}

...
...    

}
```

AND

**OVAddPersonDialogView.swift**

```
protocol OVAddPersonDialogViewDelegate: NSObjectProtocol{
   func onClose()
   func onOpen()
}

class OVAddPersonDialogView: UIView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var delegate: OVAddPersonDialogViewDelegate?

    //MARK: IBActions

    @IBAction func btnCancelAction(sender: UIButton) {
        dismissFromView()
    }

//MARK: Constructor

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.setupView()
}

//MARK: Instance Methods

func setDelegate(tdelegate:OVAddPersonDialogViewDelegate){
    self.delegate = tdelegate
    println(self.delegate!)
}

private func setupView(){

  let ovAddPersonDialogView:UIView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("OVAddPersonDialogView", owner: self, options: nil).first as UIView
    ovAddPersonDialogView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame.size.height)
    self.addSubview(ovAddPersonDialogView)

}

func showInView(view:UIView){
    view.addSubview(self)
    self.delegate?.onOpen()
    println(self)
}

func dismissFromView(){
    println("Should close")
    println(self.delegate)
    println(self)
    self.delegate?.onClose()
}

   ...
   ...

}
```

What I want to do is to update the `ViewController` whenever the user taps the Cancel button(which I know invokes the `btnCancelAction()` method in the `OVAddPersonDialogView class`).

Now, the problem is that the `self.delegate?.onClose()` method implementation in the `ViewController` class never gets called. Executing `showInView(uiView)` method behaves as expected but when calling `dismissFromView()` `self.delegate` becomes nil for some reason.

After logging `self` from the `showInView()` and `dismissFromView()` methods, I noticed that `self` is different. So that answers the question why the delegate became **nil**.

So now, I'm wondering how come `self` is of different instance after calling `showInView()` and `dismissFromView()` methods?

Any thoughts regarding my problem would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Log out `self` in the showInView and dismissFromView methods. I suspect they are different objects.

Comment: @jrturton yes I've tried logging them and they seem to be different objects. That answers the question why the delegate becomes **nil**. So now I'm wondering how come `self` had two separate instances? Is it because of the `required init()` and `override init()` constructors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured the answer to my own question. The real problem exists in the **nib** file of `OVAddPersonDialogView`. Instead of setting its file owner's custom class to `OVAddPersonDialogView`, I had it placed in the root `View`'s custom class which causes the `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` to be called thus, creating a separate instance of `self`

Comment: Well done! I suspected it was something like that but doesn't it feel good to get there on your own!

Comment: @jrturton yeah you're right, thanks btw for the hint! :D